# Learning Rate Decay in Lasagne

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning, lasagne

I am using nesterov momentum for updating the weights of a Convolutional Neural Network. I am using Lasagne for building a CNN. How to implement learning rate decay for every epoch?

```
prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)
params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss, params, learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
train_fn = theano.function([input_var_1, input_var_2, target_var], loss, updates=updates)
```

Comment: Can you use adam like in Keras? If so, you could just use adam or one if its variants...

Answer (score 3):

Define your learning rate as a graph element

```
...
learning_rate = T.scalar(name='learning_rate')
updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss, params, learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
...
```

Add your learning rate node to train_fn

```
train_fn = theano.function([input_var_1, input_var_2, target_var, learning_rate], loss, updates=updates)
```

Now you're able to adjust the learning rate for example like this:

```
base_lr = 1e-4
lr_decay = 0.8

for epoch in range(epochs):
    lr = base_lr * (lr_decay ** epoch)
    loss, updates = train_fn(input_1, input_2, target, lr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing something:

```
prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)
params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss, params, learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
train_fn = theano.function([input_var_1, input_var_2, target_var], loss, updates=updates)
```